# migrating down your latest migrations

Tags: migration, typeorm

First a theoritical background:

If I create 3 new migration files that would change 3 tables after I `migrate up` , should `migrate down` revert all 3 tables effected by the latest migration or just the last table that was effected?
(*my guess the former should happen*)

The problem:

In `typeorm` when I `typeorm migrate:revert` , it only effects the last table that was effected by the latest migration, so I'm wondering if my guess was correct or not. What is the usual behaviour for `migrate down` in general(irrespective of the ORM used).

Is this an expected behaviour or  there a possible solution for `typeorm` to keep track of the latest migration changes to revert all the changes in latest migration?

I have found this in their documentation:

> If for some reason you want to revert the changes, you can run:
> typeorm migration:revert
> This command will execute down in the latest executed migration. If you need to revert   multiple migrations you must call this command multiple times.

But, if what I expect is true, then an orm should already have the tools to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, typeorm doesn't have this feature as of yet, you migrate down your stuff migration by migration(one migration file content at a time).

Comment: Slight correction: You don't migrate down table by table, but you migrate down migration by migration. If you have created a separate migration for each table, then each migration will only affect one table, but it will always run the `down` function in the migration and affect all the tables that were created with that migration.